# Why use std::back_inserter instead of end() during std::copy?

Tags: c++

I have seen `std::copy()` using `std::back_inserter` but I used `std::end()` and both works. My question is, why was `std::back_inserter` needed if `std::end()` does the works just fine?

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <iterator> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    // Declaring first container 
    vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 }; 

    // Declaring second container for 
    // copying values 
    vector<int> v2 = { 4, 5, 6 }; 

    // Using std::back_inserter inside std::copy 
    //std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));  // works
    std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.end());  // also works
    // v2 now contains 4 5 6 1 2 3 

    // Displaying v1 and v2 
    cout << "v1 = "; 

    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { 
        cout << v1[i] << " "; 
    } 

    cout << "\nv2 = "; 
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { 
        cout << v2[i] << " "; 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin());`? Using `v2.end()` is undefined behavior. It may appear to work since you never look at the size, if `capacity` was big enough. Even then, your display loop for `v2` won't work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No they both give same v2 = {4 5 6 1 2 3}

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I meant end().

Comment: Then you have undefined behavior that only *looks* like it works. If you try to add more elements it will eventually fail. And try to copy `v2` and see if it *actually* contains those elements.

Comment: You could also try this with an `std::list` where it will almost certainly not look like it works. It should crash much more quickly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first one inserts values into the vector, the other one is *undefined behavior*, it writes items into the spot just past the end of the vector.

Try printing the resulting vector:

```
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));  // works
for (auto x : v2) cout << " " << x;
cout << endl;
```

Prints

```
 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

Whereas

```
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.end());
for (auto x : v2) cout << " " << x;
cout << endl;
```

Prints

```
 4 5 6
```

(In Debug mode raises an assertion failure)

The fact that it works for you in *your particular compiler* doesn't make it correct. Appearing to work is a typical manifestation of UB.

Comment: Most likely, one issue, that contributed to the OPs confusion, was not printing the contents, based on the size of the `std::vector`, but based on hardcoded indices, effectively reading past the end of the `std::vector`, in addition to writing there.

Comment: Ok so it was all just illusion cause when I thought was working. When I printed your way. I do see only  4 5 6.

Comment: @user463035818 removed :p

Comment: @rustyx when you said "it inserts items into the spot just past the end of the vector" you mean that happens when we do `std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.end());` right?

Comment: Yes, because end() will not modify the size and will not ensure enough capacity.